# Reset ion-input/range value whenever it is loaded on screen

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like my ion-input and ion-range slider to reset their value to the value set by [(ngModel)] whenever the slider/input is loaded on the page. The slider/input fields show when the user presses a button on the page. Then the user has the option of saving their inputs or canceling, which hides the slider/input. When they cancel I want it so that the value of the slider/input is set to whatever the input was when they last saved. Currently anything a user inputs is kept on the slider/input if they cancel, although the value set by [(ngModel)] is not updated.

I'm using HTML, Angular and TypeScript for this portion of the program.

Here's the important code:

```
<div *ngIf="showFilter">
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="aFilter" type="number" name="a" min="0"></ion-input>
    <ion-range
        min="1"
        max="3"
        snaps="true"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        [(ngModel)]="bFilter">
    </ion-range>
    <ion-button shape="round" (click)="showFilter=false; filter()">Submit</ion-button>
    <ion-button shape="round" (click)="showFilter=false">Cancel</ion-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
In ngOnInit() as soon as the component is loaded: 

ngOnInit() {
  this.aFilter.value = '';
}
```

Comment: I am unsure how this will help my problem. I've already initialized aFilter's value when the page is loaded. I want the value shown when the ion-slider and ion-input are made visible to be the value of aFiler/bFilter.